# Ubuntu Trusty on EC2 - apt-upgrade with 403 forbidden

Tags: ubuntu, apt

When I run `apt-get upgrade`, I'm getting this error:

```
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
Need to get 413 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main shared-mime-info amd64 1.2- 0ubuntu2 
403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/shared-mime-info/shared-mime-info_1.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
```

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: Long time...But, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

In case you've already tried with

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

And it didn't work, you might be hitting [this APT + Amazon's S3 bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/987182). You might want to try with these solutions:

```
# echo "Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth "0";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90-fix-s3
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install your-package-name
```

And if that doesn't work, simply stop using Amazon's S3 as your Ubuntu repositories and switch back to the original ones:

```
# sed -i 's/us-east-1/us/g;' /etc/apt/sources.list
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install your-package-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your apt database is out of date. Re-run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

If that does not fix the issue, you will need to speak with those that maintain that repository.

Comment: I'm running that command directly before `apt-get upgrade`, as I always do.