# apt-get on aws won't install zip

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apt

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-21-generic i686) on AWS.

When I try and install `unzip` I get the following errors:

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    gir1.2-gudev-1.0 libgudev-1.0-0 netcat-traditional python-gi
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
    zip
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   unzip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 184 kB of archives.
After this operation, 387 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main unzip i386 6.0-7ubuntu1.1
    403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_6.0-7ubuntu1.1_i386.deb  403      Forbidden
    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've tried `update` and `--fix-missing` and everything else mentioned and still can't get it to work.  A few other packages seem to `install` OK.  But, it seems in the last month I've gotten no updates when doing `apt-get update` then `apt-get upgrade`.  Maybe that is normal. It seems like I was getting more before.

Running `apt-get update` seems to pull down information and make connections.

Is it that I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and not the latest? That would seem odd.

I've changed none of the apt-get config files.

I've followed the advice from [Ubuntu Trusty on EC2 - apt-upgrade with 403 forbidden](https://serverfault.com/questions/588456/ubuntu-trusty-on-ec2-apt-upgrade-with-403-forbidden) and it doesn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You are running a version of Ubuntu which is past its [end of life date](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). You can no longer install software from the repositories as they are [moved](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/75668) shortly after the release hits EOL.

The preferred method of dealing with this is to upgrade to the latest long-term support (LTS) release. If you truly need old packages from an EOL distribution, you can [find them on old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Also See my answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/286053/how-to-install-old-packages-for-ubuntu-9-04/286054#286054

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but I won't advise it. It's really best to get off of EOL releases as soon as possible.

Comment: Agreed, although not always possible due to constraints outside of the person's control